# LAN PC couldn't connect MySQL server

Tags: mysql, windows, ubuntu, connection

This is madness.

In my Windows 7 laptop (LAN IP:192.168.1.201) I'm running a MySQL Server (3306 default port).
I have ZoneAlarm set up to enable any communication for 'mysqld.exe' and port 3306 on TCP/IP.
I have Windows' Firewall rule set up to enable communications through port 3306.
And I have Windows's host file set up with:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

I run '`netstat -na | grep 3306`' and got:

```
TCP   0.0.0.0:3306   0.0.0.0:0   LISTENING
TCP   [::]:3306      [::]:0      LISTENING
```

But, when I try to connect from other laptop (with Ubuntu) inside the LAN, got this responses.

For '`ping 192.168.1.201`'

```
PING 192.168.1.201 (192.168.1.201) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.201: icmp_req=1 ttl=128 time=0.753 ms
```

For '`telnet 192.168.1.201 3306`'

```
Trying 192.168.1.201...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

So, whenever I want to connect from Ubuntu's laptop to my Windows', I got:

For '`mysql -u XXXX -h 192.168.1.201 -p XXXX`'

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.201' (110)
```

I've even tried out dissabling all firewalls.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Is the user you are using allowed tyo connect remotely to your mysql server? Maybe the user you are using can only connect from localhost (see the host for your user at mysql.user table)

Comment: Root users by default tend to be restricted to localhost access by default (as far as I remember) you'll have to change the Host field on mysql.user for root, this could be the problem. But also, as stated by @cuewizchris this could be a bind-address problem. The my.ini file should be there, as it is the configuration file for mysql. The file should be on your Installation Directory (if you are not using xamp or wamp).

Answer (score 2):

It may be that your MySQL is configured not to listen to any connection attempts from outside.

Have a look inside your `my.ini`. If you find a line like this:

```
bind-address 127.0.0.1
```

...comment it out by putting a `#` in front and restart your MySQL server process, because this line causes MySQL to play dead even to telnet connection attempts like the one you made.

Of course, there may be other possible reasons blocking access to your database, but this is a common one.

Comment: There was not such line